# ContextMenuStrip opened event doesn't fire after opeing event

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

HI everyone,

I have a UserControl with a ContextMenuStrip attached to it.

I want to display ContextMenu base on which object was clicked on the surface of the control.

The issue is that, at the first launch, when I right-click on the control's surface, the contextMenuStrip doesn't show up!

I set breakpoint inside both contextMenuStrip_opening and contextMenuStrip_opened event but it seems that only contextMenuStrip_opening get fired.

What happened?

In what situation the contextMenuStrip doesn't show up?

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't do such things as marking e.Cancel = true or not assigning the control. If it was, I had fought out by debugging.

I don't know why, but I add e.Cancel = false at the beginning of ContextMenuStrip_Opening event handler then it works fine.

Comment: Wow, I didn't believe it at first but if you set e.Cancel to false it does work, that's been bugging me for days.

Answer (score 1):

I had some problem with UserControl, but e.Cancel = false dont work for me

I use next

```
 private void itemMenu_Opened(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.itemMenu.Focus();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the symptom is that the `ContextMenuString` does not show at all, I would bet that your code assigns `true` to the `e.Cancel` property in the `Opening` event handler.

If the menu shows, but the `Opened` event handler is not invoked my guess would be that the event handler for the `Opened` event is not attached for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Although the problem has been a long time ago, it is hoped that those who need it in the future will be able to see it.

I had the same problem.
According to the source of `ContexMenuStrip` opening event:

```
 CancelEventArgs openEventArgs = new CancelEventArgs(/*cancel=*/(DisplayedItems.Count == 0));
 OnOpening(openEventArgs); 

 openingEventCancelled = openEventArgs.Cancel;

 if (!openingEventCancelled) {
 // do the actual work to open the window.                            
 if (TopLevel) {
    ReparentToActiveToolStripWindow();
 }
 //...other logics
 finally{
    if (!openingEventCancelled) {
       OnOpened(new EventArgs());
    }
 }
```

when `DisplayedItems.Count == 0`, the opening eventArgs `e.Cancel = true`.

so it will be occurred when you set some ContextMenuItems visible to true in opening event, also set all ContextMenuItems visible to false in closing event or other after opening event.